# What are the different factors involved in ageing?

Tags: pathology, death

**This is a big edit of the previous question**

Thanks to first comments and answers of the previous question, here is a more specific question:

An organism faces ageing. This ageing is linked with differentiated stem cells, who are not able to duplicate indefinitely. They reached an Hayflick limit. At some point, the lack of stem cells able to duplicate correctly enters the degradation of the organism.

Now, given this information, my documentation showed factors of ageing:

- Loss of Telomere during replication: At each replication, the lack of telomeras enzyma in a differentiated stem cell triggers the loss of some of the telomere. At the moment all the telomere is lost (when the number of duplication reaches the Hayflick limit), the cell enters senescense.

What are other factors that involve in the ageing of an organism? I'm specifically interested in:

- Factors linked to the organism behaviour

Not in:

- Factors linked to agression (this part would be too important)

In Factors linked to the organisme behaviour, could be identified:

- Skeleton degradation: do degradations of skeleton exist and how do the body take care of the skeleton?
- Muscular degradation: musculare degradation does not seem to occur as long as minimal physical effort is done
- Healing: this is not a complete repair-process, as healing often leaves marks: what is the reason of such partial achievement?

**EDIT**
One more question: Is the theory of gene-based ageing based on some specific genes, or only on the alteration of DNA by external causes (radiations, raidcals...)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time, and read the Help to find out what types of questions are acceptable here. Those regarding hypothetical situations are not, and medical rather than biological questions are more suited to SE Medical Sciences.

Comment: Sort of a "catch 22" ; anyone over 90 has some compromised health condition. And tradition is to put some cause on the death certificate other than "old".

Comment: @blacksmith37 But then why do anyone over 90 has compromised health condition?
David I understand the rule but I asked one question. The side question is only there for understanding of what I am asking

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this question the way you phrased it. Nothing on this earth is immune to physical wear and tear. A tractor can't get sick, yet it won't run forever if fuel is supplied. Much of the pathology in old age is simply the result of some kind of "wear and tear" (e.g. atherosclerosis.) If there was no wear and tear  of any kind (which is impossible), sure, anything could last forever.

Comment: @anongoodnurse But how does wear and tear come? Because a tractor is worn outby friction and temperature changes, but if you change the spare parts it will be functionnal forever. And our body produces by itself its spare parts (it produces new cells all the time)

Comment: No, you can't change out worn tractor parts, that's evading the issue. The body does not make "spare parts". You can't grow a new heart or new kidneys. There is friction in blood vessels from blood rushing by. You can't escape Physics, and I don't want to argue. Reading will serve you better than arguing.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Please calm down I am not arguing, I am trying to understand the concepts and physical laws behind ageing: is it some sort of entropy?

Comment: From the [help/dont-ask], *`If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`* Please familiarize yourself with how this site works by taking the [tour] and then reading through the [help] pages starting with [ask].

Comment: @tyersome Please don't put your own appreciation on my question like that: I am asking a question, I got partial answers so I ask for details. This is not a discussion.

Comment: @tyersome About your comment and to people saying it's a stupid question, I would like to highlight that Calico Labs work on that since 2013. So this is at least a plausible subject, thus a question on that subject is not stupied

Comment: I see no comments saying this is a "stupid question" — it is however poorly written. Some examples: you ramble over multiple subjects, include irrelevant details, and use made up words (e.g. elderness — that is why it was underlined in red when you typed it in). You are also expected to demonstrate that you have done some background research before posting. If you want a positive response, I suggest reading through the [help], doing some research (document this with citations to reliable sources), and then rewriting (make sure your edits address the feedback you already got).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has multiple problems (documented in comments from multiple users) including multiple questions, no evidence of prior research, and being likely to generate opinion/discussion. Despite community input poster has not attempted to make improvement.

Comment: @tyersome To be honest I have only got input as "question does not apply" and that's it

Comment: @totalMongot I think the biggest issue is that it seems to be mostly an invitation for discussion, rather than a specific, answerable question. That doesn't make it a bad or stupid question, it's just that its more of a discussion/philosophical question rather than a biological one. The philosophical part is about [proximate/distal causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_and_ultimate_causation) and which to emphasize. Any level of explanation is defensible; which level is "best" is an opinion.

Comment: I voted to close this question, so it is clear that I do not condone it. However I feel that one should show a little simple kindness to posters whose first language is not English and help improve their questions and their fluency, by correcting questions. Poster: Note 1. that in English we talk about "ageing" (the process) and "old age" (the condition) — "elderliness" exists only in dictionaries. 2. Your use of pathology is incorrect. I am not an expert on medical terms, but in general speech you do not suffer from a pathology, but a disease, a broken ankle etc. 3. Try to keep it simple.

Comment: @David THank you for th input, I edited the question also for the other issues (too broad, opinion based..)

Comment: Edit added to the question to focus on the different parts of the body that suffers from degradation

Answer (score -2):

Another rephrasing of the question could be :

#### "are humans *potentially* immortal?"

which we (as eukaryotes) are **not**, because of the end replication problem in DNA polymerase activity- due to the unidirectional nature of DNA synthesis. During semiconservative replication the end of the lagging strand  (3'-end) of the DNA is not possible to synthesise by polimerase δ (POLD1, POLD2, POLD3, POLD4), which  discontinuously synthesizes approximately 150 to 200 base pairs long okazaki fragments in 5'-3' direction (DNA-POL δ always moves in 3'-5'over the template, but the template for the lagging strand is 5'-3' itself). This causes periodic breaks in polymerisation, and the reattachment needs RNA-primers to be present.

The last RNA primer at the 3' end of the DNA sits at a distance of about 70-100 bp to the very 3' end of the DNA, therefore about 50- 100 bp of DNA length is lost every cell division. (see http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/26/11/1167)

To not loose coding (Exons) nor regulatory (Introns,etc) DNA sequences, telomere are present at the end of the DNA. They are repeat sequences of *TTAGGG* in vertebrates that loop to protect the terminal regions of chromosomal DNA from progressive degradation and other false altercation.

However since these telomere get shorter in somatic cells every division cycle , you could argue humans have a natural "*due date*". Luckily the germline is potentially immortal due to the activity of a reverse transcriptase-enzyme *Telomerase*, that elongates telomere; badly its also active in most cancer cells.

Telomere where discovered by Barbara McClintock who was who was awarded the 1983 Nobel Prize in Physiology.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to *overly* associate telomeres with aging of *organisms* rather than aging of *cells*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really understand : in the beginning you say "we are not immortal as eucaryote" (which means? sorry I 'm not good at biology ^^) and in the end you say that we are potentially immortal thanks to telomere?
@BryanKrause Interesting, are elderness diseases linked to organism aging or cells aging?

Comment: @totalMongot Well, by the contrast I'm making by definition elderness diseases are a part of organism aging. It's just that this answer conflates that with telomeres which have some role in limiting how many times cells divide, it's just overly simplistic to think that's the specific process behind aging of an organism.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the problem in the process you described is cancer?

Comment: I found in some article  (I doubt of them BTW) that telomere shortening might also affect stem cells: is it true?
https://novoslabs.com/causes-of-aging-stem-cell-exhaustion/

Comment: Hello, could you please gives more hindsight about the specificity of eucaryote that makes us vulnerable to the end replication problem in DNA, compared to others? Is it because non-eucaryot organisms do not have DNA (because no nucleus in cell)?

Comment: Of course the have DNA!